# How do I grab the top result of a Google search?

Tags: php

In a PHP script I want to get just the URL of the top result of a Google search and redirect to it. I could scrape it but is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the I'm Feeling Lucky function.

Example:

> http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=**stackoverflow**&**btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky**&aq=f&oq=

It automatically takes you to the top result.